# What will happen to .Net Core 3 websites once .Net 5 is released?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-5

Following this question [Is .NET Core == .Net Framework 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955459/is-net-core-net-framework-5)

I am just about to make the colossal move to .Net Core 3 which means rewriting some very large applications from scratch. I am at the most basic Hello World level on .Net Core 3 so don't want to start this massive migration if .Net 5 will be out next year and change everything again.

If I start a project in .Net Core 3 today, am I going to have to change it again to work with .Net 5 going forward next year or will it just work in .Net 5?

Comment: .Net 5 isn't a different framework, it is based on .net core, it will be released .Net Core 3 and then the 3.1, They will skip the version 4 because it would confuse users that are familiar with the .NET Framework. Finally they will release the .Net 5

Comment: `so don't want to start this massive migration if .Net 5 will be out next year and change everything again`- From .NET 5.0 there will be only one runtime for all .NET application that does not mean that there will lot of breaking changes in ASP.NET Core framework. Runtime and Framework are not the same thing.

Comment: I mean will the basic stuff all stay the same like having a Startup.cs and Program.cs files? It seems to have changed quite a bit from .Net framework to .Net Core. I find MS stuff very confusing coming from ColdFusion

Comment: Most things will probably stay the same because .net 5 is .net core, also you aren't forced to upgrade to the latest versions with .net and any breaking changes are well documented by Microsoft as well as upgrade paths.

Comment: Since the preview releases are out now, you could start development against .NET 5 in anticipation. There are obviously tradeoffs to that approach. You probably won't want to launch prior to its release, which is anticipated in November, so that should be factored into your decision. And, as a preview, you're going to encounter bugs and be restricted to preview versions of Visual Studio. But you're also going to be able to keep your code up-to-date with any new .NET 5 features you might want to take advantage of, as they release. (Currently, ASP.NET 3.1 and ASP.NET 5 are virtually identical.)

Comment: I have migrated today our companies quite big Net Core 3.1 app to DotNet 5 almost without problems - it took me 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 5 will be a logical successor to .NET Core 3.0, with the ecosystem aiming to merge multiple "stacks" (ASP.NET, Xamarin, WPF,..) into one platform and there was a marketing decision to drop the "Core" part of the name while not confusing it with the existing 4.* version of .NET Framework.

If you migrate an application to .NET Core 3.0, you are set up good for .NET 5/6/+.

Also note that .NET Core 3.1 - scheduled for November 2019 - is going to be a long-term support (LTS) release that will be supported with patches for at least 3 years.

There may or may not be breaking changes between .NET Core 3.0 and .NET 5, since it is a major version bump, but the migration cost will not be as huge as moving from classic ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: We couldn't take the risk and migrated to NodeJS with Vue instead