# Is .NET version 8 the same as .NET core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-8.0

I am new to .NET and I need to work on a project using .NET core.
I saw a tutorial from 3 years ago using .NET Core 3.1
now when I download the tools I saw the latest version is .NET 8 but there is no "Core".
Please can you explain the differences and tell me if it is the same as core?

Comment: Yes, .NET 5 through .NET 8 are the ongoing continued development of the **.NET Core** platform. The "classic" (legacy, Windows-only) **.NET Framework** ended at v4.8.1 and no new version will be forthcoming

Comment: You can have a look at [What's new in ASP.NET Core 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to know more .

Comment: ".NET 5 is the next major release of .NET Core following 3.1.   ASP.NET Core 5.0 is based on .NET 5 but retains the name "Core" to avoid confusing it with ASP.NET MVC 5. " You can have a look at [What's new in .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5) and [What's new in .NET 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-8)

Comment: A short summary from Microsoft [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/introduction)  (at the bottom, history and ecosystem)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40955459/2501279 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/72240269/2501279

Comment: @marc_s _"The "classic" (legacy, Windows-only) .NET Framework ended at v4.8."_ - a small nitpick on "ended" - while (as correctly was stated) no new versions are planned, it is worth noting that it is still supported and should at least receive security updates - [Microsoft .NET Framework Lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) (unlike for example .NET 5 and .NET Core 3.1 and earlier versions)

Comment: The accepted answers in the duplicates *increase* confusion because they repeat the marketing talk that somehow .NET 5 "unified" Core and Framework, when in reality only the name changed.